# WCF Service methods + Synchronous calls from javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, wcf, service

I have written a WCF service and am trying to call the service methods in a script in my ASPX page.

Eg:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

<!--

        function Test() {
          **// The following call is an Async call.  
          tempuri.org.IService.GetData(1,OnRequestComplete, OnError, "");**
        }

        function OnRequestComplete(result, state) {
            var textBox = $get("txtInput");
            textBox.value = result;

        }
        function OnError(result) {
            var textBox = $get("txtInput");
            textBox.value = result;
        }

    //-->    
</script>
```

What I want is to be able to call the service method "synchronously"

eg: **var result = tempuri.org.IService.GetData(1);**

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

I believe there's no ability to do synchronous calls in Javascript - the AJAX libraries will always return while waiting for a remote response.

Can you explain why you want to do this?

Edit:

In answer, you should use this method:

- In the onclick event handler for your form submit button: Make the webservice validation call, and immediately return false (so the form does not submit). *It would be a good idea to display to the user a 'Validating' type message, so they know what is happening here.*
- If you get a valid response, then use `document.form.submit();` to submit the form to the server.
- If you get an invalid response, or a server error, then display to the user a message to that effect.

Comment: I want to write a custom javascript function for a custom validator and the custom script should invoke my wcf service "synchronously". If the call is async, the page posts back and the request to wcf doesn't complete !

Comment: Then you should look at another way of doing this. Have this validation occur first, and then depending on the result THEN submit the form.

Comment: The logic for validation is in my service :)
So the page should wait until my service comes back with validation results.

Comment: Clarified the approach you should use in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you use regular AJAX you can make your call synchronous.

See: http://www.w3schools.com/Ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp
and scroll down to the part "Asynchronous - True or False?"

Here I use AJAX but sometimes it hangs
www.DomainGuarder.com